# Save data to external file

Tags: c#, file-io, save

I've a

```
List<MyCustomClass> mcc = new List<MyCustomClass>();
```

When the program runs it collects data from the user, based on which it assembles the List.
I'd like to store the data, so that the next time the program runs, it would remember.

I'd like to summarize, what methods do I have available to do just that?

- with a StreamWriter i can save text to a "file.txt".
- I've heard an option regarding saving to XML file.
- database: I've no experience with them yet

Are there any more options? 
Which one  would you recommend for this particular reason, and why?

Comment: I would save to a file based DB. Try SQL Server Compact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a database for sure, but if this is a program for a single user tiny app I would use either:

[SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx)

or a Document store database (No Sql)

[RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)

With RavenDB you can just take your `MyCustomClass` object and drop it straight into this storage and get it back out again.

Answer (score 1):

You should save it to a database in most cases. Databases are made for storing, and more importantly retrieving data.

If you save it to a text file you will be responsible for formatting the data, and then write even more code to retrieve it. What if you need to add a new property to MyCustomClass?

Serializing it in XML and writing it to text is better, as the formatting is done for you, but you still have the problem of retrieving it later. What if you have 1000 records and need to get record #495? You will have to read the whole text file, possible serializing all the text back into your object and search for the record. Very slow.

Databases solves this all for you. If it is a small app there are even databases that are normal files! For bigger projects you will need a centralized database anyway, so you should definitely give it a go